# choosing components in Vaadin

Tags: java, components, vaadin

My task is to create a grid with different cars on one axis, and different dates on another one. The content of the grid is going to be different tasks that are going to be carried out by different cars on different days. Basically - its a scheduling program. There has to be a drag and drop function between a list of tasks and the grid. I've been trying to get started all day but have not come far. I really need your help me with the following:

What component should I use to create the grid? Labels for different dates with boxes that together form a grid, or should I use a specific grid function?

What component should I use to create the list of tasks? I would like to be able to add tasks to the list that I can then drag out to the grid, but it's not a requirement. Ive tried to use the Listselector because of its persuasive list-appearance, but as the name might reveal its a selector. I really cant find any method to add things to the list, or for that matter to create the drag function?

I would be exteremly thankful if you would lend me a helping hand. And please - feel free to PM me or write a comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the Vaadin Demo site? They have many widgets used in various scenarios. Click to see the source code.

Here is one that does almost exactly your case: [Drag items between tree and table](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/drag-drop/dragdrop-table-tree).

Vaadin is brilliantly designed, with consistency. Once you learn about a few widgets you will see the same patterns being used elsewhere. In particular, study the Item and Container interfaces and classes, as discussed in this chapter [Collecting Items in Containers.](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.container.html)

Read various chapters the Book of Vaadin web site. Lots of info and examples.